# Where's the default tmux configuration file?

Tags: tmux

I'm looking for the default `.tmux.conf` or something like it. I'm trying to get rid of some noise in the status line that the default creates.

Comment: In case that helps, I'm taking great care of my tmux.conf and I'm sharing it on github: https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux

Comment: the answer can be found at the tmux-FAQs: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-see-the-default-configuration

Answer (score 22):

The default configuration is not available as a normal configuration file; it is part of the source code (thus built into the compiled program).

You can examine parts of the configuration with the commands `list-keys` and `show-options`:

```
tmux list-keys         # show current bindings

tmux show-options -s   # show current server options

tmux show-options -g   # show current global session options
tmux show-options      # show current session options

tmux show-options -gw  # show current global window options
tmux show-options -w   # show current window options
```

With *tmux* 1.7, `show-options` can also show you the value of a single option (prior versions can only list all the options from the specified class):

```
tmux show-options -gw window-status-format
```

---

If you are interested in the default configuration that a “pristine” server would have, then you can examine those items like this:

```
tmux -L unconfigured -f /dev/null start-server \; list-keys \; show-options -s \; show-options -g \; show-options -gw
```

The `-L unconfigured` bit specifies a server socket that you are probably not already using (if you happen to have a server using that socket name, then just pick some other, unused name). The `-f /dev/null` makes sure that the server does not use your normal `~/.tmux.conf` configuration file (though, short of a custom build, there is no way to skip the `/etc/tmux.conf` system configuration file). The `start-server` command is necessary because only certain commands will automatically start a server.

---

If you are interested in looking at the source code here are the areas of interest:

- the options are defined in [`options-table.c`](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/options-table.c) in these arrays:

  - `server_options_table`
  - `session_options_table`
  - `window_options_table`
- the bindings start in `key_bindings_init()` in [`key-bindings.c`](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/key-bindings.c), but some of the details are spread out with the individual command definitions (e.g. `cmd_select_window_key_binding()` in [`cmd-select-window.c`](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/cmd-select-window.c)).

Comment: also a good answer which perhaps helps one or two to understand the concept and the reason for the different kinds of settings: https://superuser.com/a/759156/403979

Answer (score 3):

There should be one in your `$HOME/.tmux.conf` specific to your user and a system-wide config file located at `/etc/tmux.conf`

Comment: I made the `$HOME/.tmux.conf` myself, and `/etc/tmux.conf` doesn't exist.

Comment: Most Linux distributions do not ship with any tmux config files, not even empty ones. But if you do create one tmux should parse through these config files. Do you find any particular option not being retained when you restart tmux ?