# Difference between global, server, session and window options

Tags: tmux

The tmux manual discusses various types of options, for example *global options*, *server options* and so on. The question [Where's the default tmux configuration file?](https://superuser.com/questions/560465/wheres-the-defaul-tmux-configuration-file) also refers to some of these types of configuration.

Some of these types are easy to understand: window options deal with things that relate only to a single window. For example "allow-rename": windows have names, sessions do not. For other types, however, the distinction is not very clear.

What is the difference between

- server options (`set-option -s`),
- global session options (`set-option -g`),
- session options (`set-option`),
- global window options (`set-window-option -g`),
- window options (`set-window-option`)?

Also, what are the inheritance rules for these types?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are three distinct classes of options: server, session, and window. These classes are exclusive: each option belongs to only one of the classes. There is never any inheritance between the option classes.

There is only one level of server options, so there is no inheritance there (although you can have multiple, independent servers using the `-L` or `-S` command line flags).

The session and window options each use a two-level hierarchy: the global session (window) options provide default values for session (window) options that are unset. Session and window options are all initially unset, so new sessions/windows will automatically use the global session/window option values.

When a session option is set (`set-option`), the newly set value will override the global value for that session. To go back to using the global value, unset the option (`set-option -u`). Changes to the global session option values will affect all sessions in which that option is currently unset. The same idea applies to the window options (except setting a window option overrides the value for an individual window instead of an individual session).

---

For example, to find the effective value for the `base-index` session option for a particular session:

- Check the session’s `base-index` option (i.e. what you get from `tmux -t «target-session» show-options base-index`<sup>*</sup>).

  1. If the session has a `base-index` value, then use it.
  2. If the session’s value was not set, then use the global value (i.e. what you get from `tmux show-options -g base-index`).

Similarly, to find the effective value for the `mode-keys` window option for a particular window:

- Check the window’s `mode-keys` option (i.e. what you get from `tmux -t «target-window» show-options -w mode-keys`<sup>**</sup>).

  1. If the window has a `mode-keys` value, then use it.
  2. If the window’s value was not set, then use the global value (i.e. what you get from `tmux show-options -gw mode-keys`).

---

<sup>* Older versions of *tmux* do not accept an option name argument for `show-options`. With those versions you will have to do something like *grep* for it: `tmux -t target show-options | grep '^base-index '`.</sup>
<sup>** This is the same as `tmux show-window-options base-index`, if you like that better. The related command for the global window options is `tmux show-window-options -g base-index`.</sup>

---

Here is a diagram:

```
                 .---------------.
                ( server options  )
                 `---------------'

===========================================================

              .----------------------.
             ( global session options )    base-index 1
              `---------+--+---------'     visual-bell on
                     --/    \--
                  --/          \--
           +-----/-----+    +-----\-----+
           | session X |    | session Y |
           +-----------+    +-----------+
           base-index 0     visual-bell off

  effective values for X:
      base-index 0     (set)
      visual-bell on   (global)

  effective values for Y:
      base-index 1     (global)
      visual-bell off  (set)

===========================================================

              .---------------------.
             ( global window options )    pane-base-index 1
              `---------+++---------'     mode-keys emacs
                    ---/ | \---
                 --/     |     \---
             ---/        |         \---
         ---/            |             \---
+-------/----+    +------+-----+    +------\-----+
| window X.0 |    | window X.1 |    | window Y.0 |
+------------+    +------------+    +------------+
pane-base-index 0                   mode-keys vi
mode-keys vi

  effective values for X.0:
      pane-base-index 0   (set)
      mode-keys vi        (set)

  effective values for X.1:
      pane-base-index 1   (global)
      mode-keys emacs     (global)

  effective values for Y.0:
      pane-base-index 1   (global)
      mode-keys vi        (set)
```

Comment: To disdinguish server options from the global ones: Server options are options not applied to either session or window options. And there's only a few server options which can be listed by `show -s`. However from the usage perspective, server options are not necessary IMHO.

Comment: I mean I wish server options can also be specified with `-g` and remove `-s` just for the sake of UX simplicity. I just don't get any benefit by knowing an option is a server option.

Comment: https://man.openbsd.org/tmux#OPTIONS

Comment: I still want to know the differences and applicability of the different config commands like `set`, `setw`, `set -w`, `set -g`, etc and which kinds of options they affect.