# Tmux conf returns error at start

Tags: bash, redhat-enterprise-linux, tmux

I ssh to a remote server with TMUX. The `.tmux.conf` file is very simple:

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
set -g status-right '#(TZ=Asia/Kolkata" date +"%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M")'
```

And the relevant `.bashrc` code snippet is:

```
[ -z "${PS1:-}" ] && return
source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
```

Everytime I start TMUX or start a new window, it opens a new window with this error

```
bash: setw: command not found...
-bash: set: -g: invalid option
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

It's weird that the system does not recognize [`setw`](https://superuser.com/questions/1425920/different-between-set-g-and-setw-g-and-set) command. How can I fix it?

I'm using `Ubuntu 22.10` on `WSL` while the remote server is `Red Hat 8.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tmux.conf file was not meant to be sourced by Bash at all; it will be read directly by tmux. The tmux commands in that file are not system commands – *they are tmux commands,* and even the tmux command 'set' has nothing to do with the Bash command of the same name.

Comment: Yeah, simply deleting `source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"` solves the problem.