# What is the optimal way to set options in tmux?

Tags: tmux

This is a follow-up on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/758843/difference-between-global-server-session-and-window-options) describing inheritance.

In my config, copypasted from all sorts of places, most of the settings were set via `set -g`, except for `set -gs escape-time` and `set -gw pane-base-index`. I edited those to conform to the rest and everything seems to work.

Why tmux has so many levels and what edge cases does it cover? Is it okay to just `set -g` everything, since it's the most common option you see? If not, how do you decide what options are set on what level?

Answer (score 0):

Builtin option names are unique and tmux can work out whether they are server, session or window options so it is fine to just use `set` (for per session) or `set -g` (for global) for all of them.

If you are setting a user option (`@foo`) tmux can't work it out from the name so you need to explicitly say whether you want a server, session, window or (in 3.0 or later) pane option by giving `-s`, no option, `-w` or `-p`.

You need to know which type of options you want to see for `show-options` however. If you want to know where an option belongs, look at the man page.